# Importing and parsing calendars in OCaml

Tags: json, parsing, functional-programming, ocaml, icalendar

I am working on a scheduling/planning program in OCaml and I want to be able to use an iCal file as an input, but I can't figure out how to parse the file into my own calendar type in OCaml. Ideally, I want to be able to read an iCal file in the same way that you can read a json file using Yojson. Any ideas for how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the [ICalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) format then there is the OCaml library [icalendar](https://github.com/roburio/icalendar) that can read it. You can install it with

```
opam install icalendar
```

It is pretty undocumented so here is an example program that will read and print back a calendar.

```ml
open Format

let read filename =
  let buf = Buffer.create 4096 in
  let src = open_in filename in
  let rec loop () = loop (Buffer.add_channel buf src 4096) in
  try loop () with End_of_file -> close_in src; Buffer.contents buf

let main filename =
  match Icalendar.parse (read filename) with
  | Error failure ->
    eprintf "Failed to read file %s %s@\n%!" filename failure
  | Ok calendar ->
    printf "%a@\n%!" Icalendar.pp calendar

let () = main Sys.argv.(1)
```

Note, that I also had to write the `read` function that will read the whole file into a string. This function is not a part of the standard library but is commonly provided by other libraries, e.g., Base, Core, Batteries.

To build the program, create an empty folder, put the code into a file, e.g., `example.ml` and then issue the following command in that folder:

```
ocamlbuild -pkg icalendar example.native
```

You can then use the built binary as

```
./example.native input.ics
```

where `input.ics` is the sample input.